# ArcPy - overwrite feature service with CSV

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, csv, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to download a CSV from our project database, and then append this to a feature service in AGOL.

```
import os
import requests
import csv
import arcpy
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from arcgis.gis import GIS

print('Environment variables loaded.')

API_URL = 'https://web.lucion.co.uk/api/'
API_ENDPOINT = 'jobs/get'
USERNAME = 'removed'
PASSWORD = 'removed' 

if USERNAME == 'my_email' or PASSWORD == 'my_password':
    raise Exception("You need to change your email and password")

# Define the json post data
json_data = {
    "filters": [
        {
            "office.company": 11
        }
    ],
    "limit": 1000,
    "expand": False,
    "columns": [
        "id",
        "contract.id",
        "product_type",
        "title",
        "site.address",
        "site.lat",
        "site.lng"
    ]
}

# List to store all the rows from each page of data
all_rows = []

# Make the first request and get the initial page of data
print(f'Fetching data from API {API_ENDPOINT}...')
response = requests.post(API_URL + API_ENDPOINT, json=json_data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))

while response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()['data']
    print(f'Got {len(data["rows"])} rows.')

    # Add the rows from the current page to our total list of rows
    all_rows.extend(data['rows'])

    # If there's no 'next' key in the data, then there are no more pages
    if 'next' not in data or len(data['next']) == 0:
        break

    # If there's a 'next' key, then we need to get the next page of data
    # by including 'after' in our request with the value of 'next'
    json_data['after'] = data['next']

    response = requests.post(API_URL + API_ENDPOINT, json=json_data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
else:
    print(f'Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}')

print (f'Got {len(all_rows)} rows in total.')

csv_path = r"C:\NexGenExports\NexGenJobsExport.csv"
absolutepath = os.path.abspath(csv_path)
print(f'Writing data to CSV file at {absolutepath}...')
with open(absolutepath, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=all_rows[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(all_rows)
print(f'Data successfully written to {absolutepath}.')

# Your Arc Code:
# ArcGIS Online credentials
username = "removed"
password = "removed"

# Connect to ArcGIS Online
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", username, password)

# Get the feature service item
feature_service_item = gis.content.get("635b6b9b19cb4c3e8bdd5b80cbbf8b16")

# Get the feature layer from the item
feature_layer = feature_service_item.layers[0]

# Call the overwrite() method by passing the path to the CSV file
feature_layer.overwrite(csv_path)

# Clean up the downloaded CSV file
os.remove(csv_path)

print("CSV file downloaded and appended to the feature service successfully.")
```

However I get the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [21]:
Line 90:    feature_layer.overwrite(csv_path)

AttributeError: 'FeatureLayer' object has no attribute 'overwrite'
```

All of the code works until the bit where I wish to overwrite to ArcGIS Online.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: You could try an alternate approach. Have a template APRX with a Map. Create your CSV, create a feature class from this CSV (MakeXYEventLayer + ExportFeatures tools), add feature class to Map, you could have a lyrx file and apply symbology, and then use arcpy to Publish/Overwrite to AGOL. You could create a template feature class in the Map instead of adding and just overwrite the feature class with each CSV download. See this thread for interest: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/automate-overwrite-web-layer-feature-class/td-p/20067

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the ArcGIS API for Python much but looking at the Help file overwrite is not a method on a [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer), hence error message.  I've not tried to overwrite anything as you are doing, but may be you can delete all the features then append a new CSV as an alternative approach?  Unless there really is an overwrite method/function?

Comment: This is a nice workflow. You could achieve this by using the truncate() function in the ArcGIS API for Python, and then use the standard python library csv module to iterate through the records in the csv and add new records to the feature service using the edit_features() function with geometry module.